# Java Multiple Choice Inquiry

Tags: java

```
public void printVals (String[] items, int k) { 
    if (K < 1) {
        printVals(items, k -1);
        System.out.print(items[k] + "");
        printVals(items, k -2)

    }
}
```

suppose the following code segment has been executed:

```
string[] names = {"Pat", "Joe", "Ann", "Cal", "Amy"};
printVals(names, names.length - 1);
```

What is the output?

```
(A) Ann Cal Amy Ann
(B) Ann Cal Amy Cal Ann
(C) Ann Cal Joe Amy Joe Ann
(D) Joe Ann Cal Amy Ann
(E) Ann Cal Amy Ann
```

The correct answer is  A, but I do not know how to do it, and I am not sure if choice A is right

Comment: Write each step down on a piece of paper or use your debugger to step through each iteration.

Comment: *"The correct answer is A, but... I am not sure if choice A is right"* If choice A is right, is it right or not right?

Comment: First of all, the code does not compile, because `K` is an unknown variable (note: `k` is not the same as `K`). Assuming that this is a typo and it should have been `k`, then the answer is: none of the above. Since `k` is not `< 1`, there will be no output at all. Did you mean `k > 1` instead of `k < 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't print anything. when we invoke the method printVals() the value of k is 4 and therefore the expression k < 1 evaluates to false and method ends. It never goes to recursive call or print statement. However if you change the expression to if(k > 1) then it'll print "Ann Cal Amy Ann" i.e. Option A